# openmaptiles quickstart fails due to docker compose / invalid host header issue

Tags: docker, openmaptiles

I have sucessfully used OpenMapTiles last year to produce a tileset with the quickstart.sh command last year. I am not using a server or else, I just need the mbtiles.tiles file.

This year I wanted to renew my file. I have cloned the github reopsitory again, but when I run `./quickstart.sh germany`  within openmaptiles folder, the process stops with a notice about the host header and a makefile error at the end of the output below:

```
=====================================================================================
                       Docker check & Download images                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Please check the Docker and docker-compose version!
      : We are using docker-compose v3 file format!  see more at https://docs.docker.com/
      : Minimum required Docker version: 1.12.3+
      : Minimum required docker-compose version: 1.7.1+
      : See the .travis build for the currently supported versions.
      : Your docker system:
Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Pulling or refreshing OpenMapTiles docker images 
Using docker compose V1 (docker-compose)

Refreshing docker images... Use NO_REFRESH=1 to skip.
POSTGIS_IMAGE=openmaptiles/postgis-preloaded \
    docker-compose pull --ignore-pull-failures --quiet openmaptiles-tools generate-vectortiles postgres
 
=====================================================================================
                                Start processing                                     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : OpenMapTiles quickstart! [ https://github.com/openmaptiles/openmaptiles ]    
      : This will be logged to the ./quickstart.log file (for debugging) and to the screen
      : Area             : germany 
      : Download server  : unset (automatic) 
      : Preloaded image  : true 
      : Git version      : 6c31841f4674f15e15afde346a060cf7c22e6cdd 
      : Started          : 2023-11-12T16:43+0100 
      : Your bash version: 5.1.16(1)-release
      : Your OS          : linux-gnu
Docker version 20.10.24, build 297e128
Docker Compose version v2.17.2
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      : This is working on x86_64 ; Your kernel is:
6.2.0-36-generic
x86_64
      : --- Memory, CPU info ---- 
System memory (GB): 15.5054
SwapTotal:       2097148 kB
CPU number: 8 x bogomips    : 3600.00
MemFree:         6601088 kB
SwapFree:        2097148 kB
HugePages_Free:        0
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Stopping running services & removing old containers
Using docker compose V1 (docker-compose)
docker-compose down -v --remove-orphans
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-80484b06df7e  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-80484b06df7e  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-adfa122aeecf  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-a947da495e32  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-0a09cfc394c8  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-a947da495e32  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-adfa122aeecf  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-0a09cfc394c8  Stopping
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-80484b06df7e  Stopped
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-80484b06df7e  Removing
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-a947da495e32  Stopped
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-a947da495e32  Removing
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-0a09cfc394c8  Stopped
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-0a09cfc394c8  Removing
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-adfa122aeecf  Stopped
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-adfa122aeecf  Removing
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-a947da495e32  Removed
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-0a09cfc394c8  Removed
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-80484b06df7e  Removed
 Container openmaptiles-openmaptiles-tools-run-adfa122aeecf  Removed
 Volume openmaptiles_pgdata  Removing
 Network openmaptiles_postgres  Removing
 Network openmaptiles_default  Removing
 Volume openmaptiles_pgdata  Removed
 Network openmaptiles_default  Removed
 Network openmaptiles_postgres  Removed
docker-compose rm -fv
No stopped containers
docker volume ls -q -f "name=^openmaptiles_" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker volume rm
rm -rf cache
mkdir cache
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Existing OpenMapTiles docker images. Will use version 7.0
openmaptiles/generate-vectortiles   7.0       da2f0c61bb55   13 months ago   294MB
openmaptiles/postgis-preloaded      7.0       b84438ba01d3   13 months ago   3.39GB
openmaptiles/import-data            7.0       0c97e860465a   13 months ago   1.66GB
openmaptiles/postgis                7.0       bfb408f6b46e   13 months ago   714MB
openmaptiles/openmaptiles-tools     7.0       72fdf94a773d   13 months ago   1.24GB
openmaptiles/openmaptiles-tools     latest    5b846eb5957e   13 months ago   1.24GB
klokantech/openmaptiles-server      latest    c7dfe7244ef9   4 years ago     1.48GB
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Create directories if they don't exist
Using docker compose V1 (docker-compose)
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Removing old MBTILES if exists ( ./data/germany.mbtiles ) 
 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
====> : Downloading germany from any source...
Using docker compose V1 (docker-compose)
Downloading germany into data/germany.osm.pbf from any source
http: invalid Host header
make: *** [Makefile:373: download] Fehler 1
```

I use an Ubuntu 22.04 system.

I am pretty sure it fails as a result of my Docker Compose version being 2.17.2 (there are numerous reports on this with other applications). Still I am neither into docker nor into shell scripting enough to tell how I could fix this problem. Can someone please help out?

Comment: After all, I helped myself: I read about a similar problem in the official bug reports  - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/11154 . As suggested the docker version causes the invalid host header problem. Because I did not know how to update my (snap-installed) docker I deinstalled it and was lucky to obtain a  more recent docker version  by installing via apt (see https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) . Here we go, everything is fine again.